# In react js when delete an item from list its remain until I reload the page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

In react js I used JSON-server for fetch data, when I delete an item its remain on the list until I reload the page delete function works fine it will remove from db.json but needs to reload the page to work, and then I add a filter to `setdata`, so please tell me what's wrong?

```
import axios from 'axios'
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'

import UserList from './UserList'

const URL = 'http://localhost:8000/user'

function App() {
  const [user, setUser] = useState(null)
  useEffect(() => {
    axios.get(URL).then(response => {
      setUser(response.data)
    })
  }, [])

  const deleteUser = id => {
    axios
      .delete(`${URL}/${id}`)
       .then(() => {
        console.log(' deleted id is:', id)
       
      })
  }

  if (!user) return null

  return (
    <div className="app">
      <UserList user={user} deleteUser={deleteUser} />
    </div>
  )
}

export default App
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code in the second `then` block is not executed . You can change your deleteUser function as below

```
const deleteUser = async (id) => {
  await axios.delete(`${URL}/${id}`);

  // delete the user
  setUser(users => users.filter((u) => u.id !== id));
};
```

Comment: As the new user array is computed using the previous state: `setUser(users => users.filter((u) => u.id !== id));`